# Python, pandas, numpy output convert to excel file

Tags: xml, excel, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I have a simply code that output looks like below:

[                                  Unnamed: 0   IV Q 2016    I Q 2017
0     Przychody netto ze sprzedaży (tys. zł)       8 078       8 877
1   Zysk (strata) z działal. oper. (tys. zł)     -15 386        -562
2             Zysk (strata) brutto (tys. zł)     -16 300        -723
3             Zysk (strata) netto (tys. zł)*      -8 500        -707
4                      Amortyzacja (tys. zł)      -1 059       1 191
5                           EBITDA (tys. zł)     -16 445         629
6                           Aktywa (tys. zł)     112 657     152 271
7                  Kapitał własny (tys. zł)*       1 127      47 725
8                   Liczba akcji (tys. szt.)  44 260,410  44 260,410
9                         Zysk na akcję (zł)       -0192       -0016
10            Wartość księgowa na akcję (zł)        0025        1078
11             Raport zbadany przez audytora           N           N
 ]

I try to convert it to excel file but unfortunately I get all output in one cell instead of nice looking table in excel. I know that the type of above result is list and I tried to modify it but the result was not satisfied. Could you advise ? Thaks

Comment: are the items in the list separated by commas?

Comment: no, they are not

Comment: what is the type of this list? is that a giant string inside? you will need to provide more information than what you have.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the output into different cells, you will need commas to split the data and convert the [CSV (comma-separated values)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values) file into an excel file.

You can use the csv class [(here for python 3)](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html) to serialize data from python into csv format (or directly into a file.)

Answer (score -1):

Excel file can be generated from CSV file which is comma separated data format. You may need to manually enter commas to separate data into cells or you can write a script for it in python. 
Once you got you csv file, you can open it in excel itself or you can use any online tool such as [this](https://convertio.co/csv-xlsx/) to convert xlsx format.